# Excel - How to create a stacked radar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a stacked radar chart in Excel similar to this:

[image: SO28503056 question example].

I have to fill color in the space between the red and blue lines. I have tried every which way I can think of but to no avail.

Would really appreciate any help.

Spreadsheet here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzj3d0iyrjfpwtx/ExcelRadar.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Is this not the right place for this question?  Is there a more appropriate forum?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean fill color between red and blue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a colored band between the red and blue lines in your example, then use the `Filled Radar` chart type. You'll have to organize your series from largest to smallest - the reverse of what it is now - and then set the fill for the smallest series to be white. This will give the appearance of just a band of color instead.

This solution might not work for you based on how complicated your real data is - I'm asuming this is just a mockup - but there's not a native way to make a "donut" version of the radar chart. (I.E, `Pie Chart` is to `Doughnut Chart` as `Radar Chart` is to `#ERROR! VALUE NOT FOUND!`)

[image: Screenshot of Radar Charts]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am really appreciative of your help.  I think I can work with this and make the chart I need to.  Thanks again.  One other question on this -- is there a way to fill the last cone (i.e. between Stat 8 and Stat 1) with data -- it can't be done with the way I am currently using.  Thanks

Comment: I can't upvote your answer yet as I don't have 15 reps yet.  The solution is great!

Comment: @user1542743 To get it to connect from 8 to 1, you just need to repeat the numbers from Stat8 in the Stat1 column on the corresponding rows.